# Autoloading namespaces

Tags: php, model-view-controller, autoload

I am creating my own MVC framework for a simple website and I want to use namespaces but I don't know how to autoload them. Here is what I tried so far:

I have a `init.php` file that has autoloading function:

```
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $file = __DIR__ . '/../' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) .'.php';
    echo $file;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require_once $file;
        echo 'yes';
    }

    use App\Core\App as App;

    $app = new App;
```

This code returns "yes" so it locates the App file.. But it also returns a fatal error: `D:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\App/../App/Core/App.phpyes
Fatal error: Class 'App\Core\App' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\App\init.php on line 28` 
Line 28 is `$app = new App;`

Here is how I am namespacing my App file:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Core\App;

    class App 
    {
    .....
```

The file structure is the following:

```
| App
|--| Core
|--|--| App.php
...
| init.php
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: It could be the directory path, is it `D:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\App\App\Core\App.php`?

Comment: No it is `D:/xampp/htdocs/MVC/App/Core/App.php`

Comment: Then like Chris says your need to change your namespace or fix the directory structure. It's echoing out what it is. `D:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\App/../App/Core/App.php`

Comment: The namespace for your class App should be `namespace App\Core;`

Comment: I changed it to `$app = new App\App;` but now I don't see `yes` from the `file_exists` function?

Comment: If your namespace is `namespace App\Core\App;` and your class is `App` it would be `$app = new App\Core\App\App()`; can you see how that's confusing lol

Comment: I tried everything and it is not working.

Comment: My first comment was wrong, but like @Benni said, it should work with the current file structure if you change the namespace to `App\Core`.

Comment: Wait I somehow have missed @Benni 's comment. I changed it and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making your own autoloader, just use the one, that comes built-in with composer. You just add the following segment in the `composer.json` file and it's done:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "": "dir_where_namespaces_start...usually_src"
  }
}
```

Also, you can't really make and "mvc framework", because MVC architecture is what the application code implements and no the framework.

Comment: This is genius and works like a charm! Didn't know that you can do this with composer.